# Why is my Activity still lagging when I run stuff in service and handler.post method?

Tags: android, service, handler

I'm confused why is my activity still lagging, I use remote service that has few methods and each has its own work like download stuff, process data, compare stuff, etc... It will run in background and update data at selected intervals and notify user of changes over notify system.

The reason why remote service, because I will eventually add a widget, and service needs to stay running even if android kills the activity, so I unbind it on each onPause().
But as far I understand that part doesn't cause my issue.

But back to my problem... so my is Activity still lagging when I run stuff in service and handler.post method.

here is the code:

```
public class WarnService extends Service {

  private Bitmap pic;
  private boolean dataUpToDate;

  private void loadData(){
    //code that downloads new data and sets the dataUpToDate variable
  }

  private void updateLayer(Bitmap bt){
    //code that updates some stuff if downloaded and local data differ
  }

  private IWarnService.Stub WServiceStub = new IWarnService.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void refreshData() throws RemoteException {
      serviceHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          loadData();
          if(!dataUpToDate){
            updateLayer(pic);
          }
        }
      });   
    }

  }
}
```

Also I wanted to add progressDialog to be updated in updateLayer(...) through Activity is a listener to this service, but thats not working well. Whats the best way to update progressDialog? Ever listener, handler, intent, or what?

So how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a Thread and attach the handler to it. So missing code was:

```
private HandlerThread hThread;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  hThread = new HandlerThread("Processing thread");
  hThread.start();
  serviceHandler = new Handler(hThread.getLooper());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  hThread.getLooper().quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your service does some heavy processing in the background, then your activity may still experience some lagging. Try decreasing the priority of the threads you use in your service. I had a similar issue in one of my projects, I tried setting my background threads' priorities to PRIORITY_BACKGROUND (or it was a constant named similar to that), and that solved it.

Edit: here you can read about thread priorities: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

Comment: I added Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND); into run() and nothing changed. I'm pretty sure my methods still run in GUI thread, I'm just not sure why.